# Failing to save notification information to Realm from FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, notifications, realm

Technically it is from a BroadcastReceiver but the broadcast is being kicked off from an implementation of FirebaseMessagingService.

I am trying to use Realm to store notification data between receiving push notifications to then be used when creating a InboxStyle notification.

My issue is that the RealmObject does not seem to getting stored down to the filesystem.
Every time a push notification is received I save a version of the notification to the realm then query to see what notifications are currently saved.  The result is always 1, the one I just saved.
I have pulled the realm file down and opened with Realm Browser and it shows 0 ChatNotifications, the Realm Object.

I do not see any errors in the logs during the processing of the notification and the opening of the application from the notification.

And I am using a different Realm database successfully as the main data storage without issue.

The Realm Object

```
public class ChatNotification extends RealmObject {

    public static final String FIELD_DATE = "messageDate";
    public static final String FIELD_CONVERSATION_ID = "conversationId";
    public static final String FIELD_USERNAME = "userName";

    @PrimaryKey
    private String messageId;
    private String conversationId;
    private String userName;
    private String messageText;
    private Date messageDate;

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(final String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getConversationId() {
        return conversationId;
    }

    public void setConversationId(final String conversationId) {
        this.conversationId = conversationId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(final String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(final String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public Date getMessageDate() {
        return messageDate;
    }

    public void setMessageDate(final Date messageDate) {
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }
}
```

RealmModule

```
@RealmModule(classes = {ChatNotification.class}, library = true)
public class NotificationModule {
}
```

Realm Configuration

```
public class NotificationRealmConfiguration {

    private static final String realmName = "notification.realm";

    public static RealmConfiguration getInstance(){
        return new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name(realmName).modules(new NotificationModule()).build();
    }

    public static Realm getNotificationRealmInstance(){
        return Realm.getInstance(getInstance());
    }
}
```

Cut down Broadcast receiver
I have also tried adding Realm.init(context); also without success.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    final Realm realm = NotificationRealmConfiguration.getNotificationRealmInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    final ChatNotification chatNotification = realm.createObject(ChatNotification.class, messageId.toString());

    chatNotification.setConversationId(conversationId.toString());
    chatNotification.setMessageDate(new Date());
    chatNotification.setUserName("Me");
    chatNotification.setMessageText("Save me");
    realm.commitTransaction();

    final RealmQuery<ChatNotification> chatQuery = realm.where(ChatNotification.class);
    long queryCount = chatQuery.count();
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your Realm version? Personally I think there is something strange going on with multi-process access.

Comment: version 3.1.2   Is there an existing git issue that I missed?

Comment: Technically Realm *should* handle multi-process notifications, although it doesn't like having multiple processes started that both start a migration. So theoretically it *should* work...

Comment: So I see the issue speaking to multi process notifications [link] (https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1091) but I don't think this applies to the issue I am running into as it is talking about updates to a realm in one process to trigger a notification in the same realm opened in a different process.  Where the issue I am having is the data not actually getting saved to the realm file when inserts are being made from the firebase messaging service.

Comment: @bryan Just wondering what happens if you store the `RealmConfiguration` instance so you only create it once?

Comment: @geisshirt Sorry for the slow reply had some other high priority features to knock out.  So I created and saved the RealmConfiguration instance on the first intent receipt  and then reused that configuration to create the Realm instance.
When doing this the ChatNotifications look to be getting persisted across BroadcastReceiver invocations.

Comment: @geisshirt I am not clear in this area but if a large number of intents are published I did not think I am guaranteed to always use the same BroadcastReceiver and have not seen any docs stating that it is a singleton in the system to make this solution bulletproof.

Comment: Try to keep the life time of you Realm instance short. Realm is caching instances so it is cheap.

Comment: I agree with the general drift of the discussion.  I don't know exactly what is going on, but I am deeply suspicious of the context in which the BroadcastReceiver is run.  I suggest that you create a singleton instance of your Realm, in the Application object, and to request it, instead of instantiating it, in the receiver.  I would *LOVE* to hear back about what you find out from that experiment.